# Build a query that pulls records based on a value in a column

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2000

My table has a parent/child relationship, along the lines of parent.id,id.  There is also a column that contains a quantity, and another ID representing a grand-parent, like so:

> ```
> id  parent.id qty Org
> 1   1         1   100
> 2   1         0   100
> 3   1         4   100
> 4   4         1   101
> 5   4         2   101
> 6   6         1   102
> 7   6         0   102
> 8   6         1   102
> ```

What this is supposed to show is ID 1 is the parent, and ID 2 and 3 are children which belongs to ID 1, and ID 1, 2, and 3 all belong to the grandparent 100.

I would like to know if any child or parent has QTY = 0, what are all the other id's associated to that parent, and what are all the other parents associated with that grandparent?

For example, I would want to see a report that shows me this:

> ```
> Org  id  parent.id  qty
> 100  1   1          1
> 100  2   1          0
> 100  3   1          4
> 102  6   6          1
> 102  7   6          0
> 102  8   6          1
> ```

Much appreciate any help you can offer to build a MS SQL 2000 (yeah, I know) query to handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
select * from tablename a
where exists (select 1 from tablename x 
              where x.parent_id = a.parent_id and qty = 0)
```

Example:

```
;with cte as
( select 1 id,1 parent_id, 1 qty, 100 org
  union all select 2,1,0,100
  union all select 3,1,4,100
  union all select 4,4,1,101
  union all select 5,4,2,101
  union all select 6,6,1,102
  union all select 7,6,0,102
  union all select 8,6,1,102

)
select * from cte a
where exists (select 1 from cte x 
              where x.parent_id = a.parent_id and qty = 0)
```

[SQL DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/16051)

Comment: Thanks, I misstated which version of SQL I have.  MS SQL 2000 doesn't support CTE.

Comment: @user1729889, i'm using CTE to demo my query, you don't have to use CTE here, check updated answer